# A simple java game InputHandler issue

Tags: java, keylistener

I have a problem with the moving of my character. I use three keys only. VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT and VK_SPACE. Moving right, left and shoot. So my problem is that when i am pressing the left or right arrow key and when i press space to shoot the character stops and i have to release the moving key and press it again to keep moving. I dont want to repressing the key. How is this possible ? Here is my source :

public class PlayerInputHandler extends InputHandler{

```
private Player player;

public PlayerInputHandler(Player player){
    super();
    this.player = player;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent pressedKey) {
    int keyCode = pressedKey.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        this.player.setCurrentWidthPos(this.player.getCurrentWidthPos() + 5);
        this.player.setIsPlayerMovingRight(true);
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        this.player.setCurrentWidthPos(this.player.getCurrentWidthPos() - 5);
        this.player.setIsPlayerMovingLeft(true);
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        if(this.player.getIsPlayerMovingLeft() == false && this.player.getIsPlayerMovingRight() == false){
            this.player.shoot();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent typedKey) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent releasedKey) {
    int keyCode = releasedKey.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        this.player.setIsPlayerMovingRight(false);
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

            this.player.setIsPlayerMovingLeft(false);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you call setIsPlayerMovingLeft/Right() in any other parts of the game?

Comment: no for now iam using it only in the code i putted here.

Comment: I tested the code and I understand the problem. But.. another question. Do you have any kind of game loop in your game? The infinite loop where game objects are updated and rendered to screen?

Comment: yes i have while loop in the engine class. Inside of it i call the main render and update methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a swing expert but this is what is happening. When you are pressing single button, lets say right arrow key, you are constantly getting new keyPressed events. When still holding the right arrow and you then press space bar and release it, you get keyPressed and keyReleased events of space bar and you are no longer getting any keyPressed events from right arrow button. Why is this happening? As I said, I don't know the internals how swing works.

Well anyway, here's the solution for you. I asked if you have game loop somewhere else in the code you didn't provide, and you do. You have to move the player's position updates to game loop's update method.

Change the keylistener:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent pressedKey) {
    int keyCode = pressedKey.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        this.player.setIsPlayerMovingRight(true);
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        this.player.setIsPlayerMovingLeft(true);
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        if(this.player.getIsPlayerMovingLeft() == false && this.player.getIsPlayerMovingRight() == false){
            this.player.shoot();
        }
    }
}
```

What was changed: removed to position update call:

```
this.player.setCurrentWidthPos()
```

Then, in your game loop's update method you should add the position updates:

```
if(player.getIsPlayerMovingRight()) {
    player.setCurrentWidthPos(this.player.getCurrentWidthPos() + 5);
}

if(player.getIsPlayerMovingLeft()) {
    this.player.setCurrentWidthPos(this.player.getCurrentWidthPos() - 5);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot it makes a huge sense but it didnt come to my mind. It works just as i wanted now.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have that condition? That doesn't allow to fire unless the player is not moving.

```
if(this.player.getIsPlayerMovingLeft() == false && this.player.getIsPlayerMovingRight() == false){
```

Comment: because i want the player to shoot only when he is not moving. But anyways even with this condition i still have the problem i described.